# Correct way to register Model with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, eslint

I'm using `mongoose` and `express.js`. From what I can gather this is the recommended way to register a model in `app.js` (`import` after connecting to the DB with `mongoose`):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/drip')
import './models/MyModel'
```

The problem with this is that it causes my `eslint` validation to fail because the `import` should always be at the top of the file:

```
error  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

Of course, moving the `import` to before the `mongoose.connect` breaks:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Target".
```

What is the clean, recommended way of working with `mongoose` when using `eslint` JavaScript standard?

Comment: Post the source of `./models/MyModel`

Comment: I hope you don't create a new connection everytime you're registering a new model. You should connect once in your initialization script and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

What we want to do here is register the model with brackets around it, and ensure express and mongoose are required at the top of the file before we attempt a connection. Here is a generic example that should help guide you:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { MyModel } = require('./models/mymodel');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect((process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/collectionname'));
const port = (process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Comment: Do you have an example with ES6 syntax? I can't get it working without other `eslint` issues and the rest of my code is ES6.